# Matlab ttest does what exactly?

Tags: matlab

Matlab ttest ["returns a test decision for the null hypothesis that the data in x comes from a normal distribution with mean equal to zero and unknown variance, using the one-sample t-test."](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/ttest.html#btrj1bc)

Can anyone clarify what exactly is output by the command ttest when run on a vector of numbers $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n$?  OK to answer in a form such as 
"it outputs the value $x$ that maximizes $y$."

I realize this is probably a trivial question for the experts, but I can't easily find a clear answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matlab's `ttest` takes your vector of data and performs a [Student's (one-sample) t-test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test#One-sample_t-test) on it, assuming that:

- the population mean you're testing against, $\mu_{0}$, is zero
- $n$ is equal to `length(x)`
- the level of statistical signficance, or [Type I error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_I_error#Type_I_error), you're willing to accept is 5%; you can change the amount of Type I error you're willing to accept in the arguments of the function

The $t$-test calculates the mean of the data in `x` (i.e., $\bar{x} =$ `sum(x)/length(x)`), and its [sample standard deviation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation#Estimation), $s$, typically with the formula

\begin{align}
s = \sqrt{\frac{1}{n - 1}\sum_{i = 1}^{n}(x_{i} - \bar{x})^{2}},
\end{align}

which corrects for the fact that $s$ estimates the true standard deviation of the population from which `x` samples.

Then, the $t$-statistic is

\begin{align}
t = \frac{\bar{x} - \mu_{0}}{s/\sqrt{n}} = \frac{\bar{x}}{s/\sqrt{n}},
\end{align}

because $\mu_{0}$ is assumed equal to zero. The documentation doesn't say, so I assume that the test is a bidirectional $t$-test, which means that `ttest` returns 1 if $t$ is greater than `tinv(0.95, length(x))` or less than `tinv(0.05, length(x))` (these are the t-statistics corresponding to a 5% level of significance; it should be the case that `tinv(0.05, length(x))` equals `-tinv(0.95, length(x))`). Otherwise, `ttest` returns 0.

Comment: Thanks.  Can you say what is tinv (again not terribly clear to me), and how is the p-value p calculated in a call [h, p] = ttest?

Comment: The student's t distribution is a probability distribution with a parameter $\nu$ (called the "degrees of freedom")  If x=tinv(0.95,nu), then for a random variable $t$ with the Student's t distribution with $\nu$ degrees of freedom, $P(t<=x)=0.95$.  In other words, x is the 95th percentile of this probabilitiy distribution.

Comment: Or if you prefer: ttest returns either 1 or zero. The array or vector fed to ttest is analyzed in order to ascertain if the vector came from a population that was normally distributed. Or not. Return of 1 means "yes" (95% CI), zero means no.  Zero can also mean that the vector did not satisfy the assumption that the mean be zero.  Other arguments to ttest have different meanings. This is for H = ttest(x);